# How to convert a list or vector into a sorted-set in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, sortedset

In Clojure, the `set` function automatically converts a `vector` or `list` into a `set`. But this is not the case for `sorted-set`:

```
(set [3 2 1])  ; #{1 2 3}
(set '(3 2 1)) ; #{1 2 3}
(sorted-set [3 2 1])  ; #{[3 2 1]}
(sorted-set '(3 2 1)) ; #{(3 2 1)}
```

Here is a solution I come up with:

```
(defn sorted-set-from-coll [coll]
    (eval (cons sorted-set (seq coll))))

(def v [3 2 1])
(sorted-set-from-coll v)        ; #{1 2 3}
(sorted-set-from-coll '(3 2 1)) ; #{1 2 3}
(sorted-set-from-coll [3 1 2])  ; #{1 2 3}
```

Is there a better / more idiomatic way to do this without eval?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`into` is also quite useful in such cases.

```
user=> (into (sorted-set) [3 1 2])
#{1 2 3}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`apply`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/apply) for this:

```
user=> (apply sorted-set [3 1 2])
#{1 2 3}
```

Comment: `into` is more idiomatic as it both conveys what's happening (one datastructure into another), and can be used with an existing destination datastructure.